# Como salvar uma imagem com pyplot?

Tags: python, gráfico, matplotlib

Estou tentando salvar um gráfico com resolução de 300 dpi no *pyplot*
*python*, mas no arquivo salvo resulta numa imagem toda preta.
Aqui está meu código:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xa = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]     
ya = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]    
xb = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]    
yb = [0, 4, 6, 10, 12, 18, 20]    
xc = [5, 7, 9, 11, 13] 
yc = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

plt.plot(xa, ya, label='A', ls='dashed', color='k', marker='o') #plot ensaio A    
plt.plot (xb, yb, label='B', ls='-.', color='k', marker='s') #plot ensaio B    
plt.plot (xc, yc, label='C', ls=':', color='k', marker='^') #plot ensaio C

plt.ylabel('produto')    
plt.xlabel('Time (h)')    
plt.title('(a)')    
plt.legend()

plt.show()    
plt.savefig ("produto.png", dpi=300)
```

Quando vou verificar o arquivo que foi salvo, está em formato *png* mas uma tela preta aparece, como se fosse uma foto inteira preta
não consegui identificar meu erro, o código roda normalmente sem gerar erros ou alertas.

Answer (score 1):

Na documentação do método [`matplotlib.pyplot.show()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.show.html) há uma orientação a respeito do uso do método `matplotlib.pyplot.show()` em conjunto do método [`matplotlib.pyplot.savefig()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html). Segue a tradução livre da orientação:

> **Salvando figuras em arquivo e mostrando uma janela ao mesmo tempo**
>
> Se você quiser um arquivo de imagem e uma janela de interface do
> usuário, use `pyplot.savefig()` antes de usar `pyplot.show()`.    Ao
> final de `pyplot.show()`(em modo blocante) a figura é fechada e
> portanto não registrada do `pyplot`. Chamar `pyplot.savefig` após
> `pyplot.show()` salvaria uma nova e portanto vazia figura.    Esta
> limitação de ordem de comando não se aplica se o show não for
> bloqueante ou se você mantiver uma referência à figura e usar
> [`Figure.savefig`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.savefig).

Então segundo essa orientação basta salvar a imagem no arquivo antes de exibir o gráfico com `pyplot.show()` que obterá o resultado desejado.

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xa = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 
ya = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
xb = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
yb = [0, 4, 6, 10, 12, 18, 20]
xc = [5, 7, 9, 11, 13] 
yc = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

plt.plot(xa, ya, label='A', ls='dashed', color='k', marker='o')
plt.plot (xb, yb, label='B', ls='-.', color='k', marker='s')
plt.plot (xc, yc, label='C', ls=':', color='k', marker='^')
plt.ylabel('produto')
plt.xlabel('Time (h)')
plt.title('(a)')
plt.legend()

#Apenas salve a figura no arquivo antes de exibir o gráfico.
plt.savefig ("produto.png", dpi=300)
plt.show()
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo acima no [Replit](https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/plotpng#main.py)</sup>

[image: Imagem gerada com matplotlib.pyplot.savefig()]

Comment: +1. É como sempre insisto, antes de usar algo comecem pela documentação, muitos erros seriam evitados se as pessoas ao invés de seguir algo como se fosse uma *receita de bolo*, gastassem um tempo lendo instruções técnicas.